# eclipse - create template for log method's arguments

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to create a template in eclipse that will put a log with all enclosing method's arguments and their values.
For example, for method:

```
foo(int i,String s)
```

the template should evaluate to something like:

```
myLogger.log("i="+i+",s=",s);
```

Is there something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

FYI - I have found an eclipse plugin that helps to do exactly what I've needed.
See here: http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-log-param/

Comment: Interesting. +1. I would still recommend using aspect, but your plugin does address what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) than a template here.
See for instance [Generic Loggin of Method Parameters?](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg04324.html)

```
/**
*
*/
package at.systemone.examples.aop;
import org.apache.log4j.*;
import org.aspectj.lang.*;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.*;


public aspect LogMethod {
  pointcut logMethod(): call (public * AOPLogging.*(..));
  before(): logMethod(){
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(assembleFullName(thisJoinPointStaticPart));
    Object[] paramValues= thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
    String[] paramNames= ((CodeSignature)thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature()).getParameterNames();
logParamValues(log, paramNames, paramValues);
  }
  after() returning(Object o): logMethod(){
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(assembleFullName(thisJoinPointStaticPart));
    // Object returnValue= thisJoinPoint.getArgs()[0];
    if (log.isEnabledFor(Level.INFO)){
    log.info("returns: '"+o+"'"); }
  }
  private void logParamValues(Logger log, String[] paramNames, Object[] paramValues) {
    if (log.isEnabledFor(Level.INFO)) { // you can even gain perfomance by using the (otherwise unsexy) fast if clause
      String nv="(";
      for (int i=0; i<paramValues.length; i++) {
        nv += paramNames[i]+" = '" + paramValues[i] +(i+1==paramValues.length?"')":"', ");
      }
      log.info(nv);
    }
  }
  private String assembleFullName(JoinPoint.StaticPart joinPointStaticPart) {
    Signature sig = joinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    String sign= sig.getDeclaringType().getName()+"."+sig.getName();
    return sign;
  }

}
```

Comment: @duduamar I didn't tested it directly. I just wanted to point out the aspectJ option.